# Java program works in terminal on host machine but not after I rsync the project directory to the VM

Tags: java, virtual-machine, javac, rsync

I have a very small program with just one java file with the main method inside. I tested the program in my Ubuntu terminal by `javac Program.java` and the `java Program.java` and all was good. Then I used rsync to send the project directory to FreeBSD that is running in a VM. There I did `javac Program.java` but when I run `java Program.java` then it is not finding the main. This is some CLASSPATH stuff - do I need to configure that in the JDK on the VM machine?

```
hk222su@freebsd-vm-group25:/home/hk222su % ls
groupAssignment1    Program.class       Program.java        Received
hk222su@freebsd-vm-group25:/home/hk222su % rm Program.class Program.java 
hk222su@freebsd-vm-group25:/home/hk222su % ls
groupAssignment1    Received
hk222su@freebsd-vm-group25:/home/hk222su % cd groupAssignment1 
hk222su@freebsd-vm-group25:/home/hk222su/groupAssignment1 % ls
1dv512_group25_assignment1.iml  out             screenshots         some_notes          src
hk222su@freebsd-vm-group25:/home/hk222su/groupAssignment1 % cd src
hk222su@freebsd-vm-group25:/home/hk222su/groupAssignment1/src % ls
Program.class   Program.java
hk222su@freebsd-vm-group25:/home/hk222su/groupAssignment1/src % javac Program.java 
hk222su@freebsd-vm-group25:/home/hk222su/groupAssignment1/src % java Program.java
Error: Could not find or load main class Program.java
hk222su@freebsd-vm-group25:/home/hk222su/groupAssignment1/src % java Program.java
Error: Could not find or load main class Program.java
hk222su@freebsd-vm-group25:/home/hk222su/groupAssignment1/src % javac Program.java
hk222su@freebsd-vm-group25:/home/hk222su/groupAssignment1/src % java Program.java 
Error: Could not find or load main class Program.java
hk222su@freebsd-vm-group25:/home/hk222su/groupAssignment1/src %
```

Comment: "java Program.java" should not have worked in your Ubuntu terminal.  There is more to the story that you are not telling us.

Comment: @swpalmer Since Java 11 (I think) you can actually execute simple programs using `java Program.java`, but it looks like the OP is using Java 8.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes, you are correct that was in Java 11 with https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/330

Answer (score 4):

When you run the compiled program, use

```
java Program
```

instead of

```
java Program.java
```